# paste dataframe on dataframe in python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, append

I want to create a dictionary in which the key is a city name and the value is a list of pandas dataframes which are formed from ID's of instances that are in that city. Currently I have the following code:

```
city_idframes_dictionary = dict()
if city in city_idframes_dictionary:
   city_idframes_dictionary[city].append(pd.DataFrame(df))
else:
   city_idframes_dictionary[city] = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

then later when I try to acces the list of dataframes by using:

```
for city in cities_new:
    frame_list = city_frames_dictionary.get(city)
    city_frames = pd.concat(frame_list, ignore_index=True)
```

However at this point I get the following error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Investigation into my steps shows that for some reason only one dataframe is added as value for each key. This is weird since I thought append would make a list of dataframes which I could later concatenate using pd.concat()

So why is only one frame added as value for a city key even though I do create several frames?

NOTE: it is not that append already concatenates the dataframes since I checked and the length corresponds to the length of one dataframe.

friendly greeting and thanks in advance for any answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
city_idframes_dictionary[city] = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

you are not defining as value a list (as you stated you wanted) but rather a dataframe. Use:

```
city_idframes_dictionary[city] = [pd.DataFrame(df)]
```

instead.

Comment: Very sharp Eypros, thank you very much for the answer it worked like a charm! :)

Comment: sorry, quite new to stackoverflow. Accepted it!